# How to Give SlideUp Effect when click on button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

my client has told me to give some effect like when we click on button than my over lay should be appeared with slideup effect.if u need example of such slideup effect than here it is:[Expedia Hotels](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expedia.bookings&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5leHBlZGlhLmJvb2tpbmdzIl0.) in this application slideup effect has been use in button click event i guess.i want to do in native android applicaiton

any help is apperciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read the Animation Guides here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html

Animations can be assigned to pretty much everything, ViewFlippers and Fragment Transactions mainly.